# How to set sliding windows frame to range BETWEEN 1 Following AND UNBOUNDED Following in snowflake

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to convert oracle sql to snowflake sql.

In oracle, I have this :

```
last_value(my_table.my_col) 
Over(Partition BY 
my_table.my_col2,
my_table.my_col3
Order By my_table.my_col4 
range BETWEEN 1 Following AND UNBOUNDED Following)
```

In snowflake as written in the documentation
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/functions-window-using.html
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html

For sliding frame, range is not supported and I have to use rows

So I have to use this :

```
slidingFrame ::=
{
   ROWS BETWEEN <N> { PRECEDING | FOLLOWING } AND <N> { PRECEDING | FOLLOWING }
 | ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND <N> { PRECEDING | FOLLOWING }
 | ROWS BETWEEN <N> { PRECEDING | FOLLOWING } AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
}
```

So I should be using this

```
last_value(my_table.my_col) 
Over(Partition BY 
my_table.my_col2,
my_table.my_col3
Order By my_table.my_col4 
rows BETWEEN 1 Following AND UNBOUNDED Following)
```

But it throws the error : "Invalid Window Frame"

Note :

I can do

```
last_value(my_table.my_col) 
Over(Partition BY 
my_table.my_col2,
my_table.my_col3
Order By my_table.my_col4 
rows BETWEEN CURRENT row AND UNBOUNDED Following)
```

and

```
last_value(my_table.my_col) 
Over(Partition BY 
my_table.my_col2,
my_table.my_col3
Order By my_table.my_col4 
rows BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED Following)
```

without error

But I need the `1 following` to get the same result.

Do you have any idea what's going on here ?

Thanks

Comment: Well, according to the syntax diagram Snowflake should support this. The workaround `FIRST_value... order by col4 DESC rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)` will probably fail, too.

Comment: Indeed, same error  "Invalid Window Frame"''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not ignoring `NULL` values so your original code looks like a `lead()` to me:

```
lead(my_table.my_col) over (partition by my_table.my_col2, my_table.my_col3
                            order by my_table.my_col4
                           )
```

No window frame is needed.  This should work in both databases.

EDIT:

@dnoeth is correct.  This is a complicated formulation.  The logic appears to be to put in the last value of the column, for all rows that do not share the final value.  That seems weird, but equivalent to this formulation:

```
first_value(my_table.my_col) over (partition by my_table.my_col2, my_table.my_col3
                                   order by my_table.my_col4 desc
                                  )
```

The difference is that this always picks up the last value in the column.  The stated code returns `NULL` for the very last value.  So, a `case` might be needed:

```
(case when rank() over (partition by my_table.my_col2, my_table.my_col3
                        order by my_table.my_col4 desc)  > 1 
      then first_value(my_table.my_col) over (partition by my_table.my_col2, my_table.my_col3
                                              order by my_table.my_col4 desc
                                  )
 end)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=658c020a6fa0595338b1642d1af66c47) is a db<>fiddle, using Postgres which accepts both queries.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it works in snowflake and give the exact same result than the original request in oracle

Comment: @CyriaquePin . . . It is also the simpler way to write the code in Oracle.  In fact, I would guess that the original code was modified multiple times, because a windowing clause is not needed for the current form.

Comment: It's LAST_VALUE **FOLLOWING**, thus it's a totally different result than LEAD. In fact it's the same as the BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING, just the last row returns a NULL instead of the actual value.

Comment: It was indeed modified multiple times, and it's only a small part of way larger request. It doesn't check null because this is followed by "IS NULL" test. My job is only to translate existing oracle code into snowflake, i didn't write the original code